# Pandas Grouping WIth Filter

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, grouping

Here is the data that I have.

```
                         title  year                        name     type  \
0                Closet Monster  2015                    Buffy #1    actor   
1               Suuri illusioni  1985                      Homo $    actor   
2           Battle of the Sexes  2017                     $hutter    actor   
3          Secret in Their Eyes  2015                     $hutter    actor   
4                    Steve Jobs  2015                     $hutter    actor   
...                         ...   ...                         ...      ...   
74996  Mia fora kai ena... moro  2011     Penelope Anastasopoulou  actress   
74997         The Magician King  2004       Tiannah Anastassiades  actress   
74998        Festival of Lights  2010             Zoe Anastassiou  actress   
74999                Toxic Tutu  2016             Zoe Anastassiou  actress   
75000           Fugitive Pieces  2007  Anastassia Anastassopoulou  actress   

                     character     n  
0                      Buffy 4  31.0  
1                       Guests  22.0  
2              Bobby Riggs Fan  10.0  
3              2002 Dodger Fan   NaN  
4      1988 Opera House Patron   NaN  
...                        ...   ...  
74996       Popi voulkanizater  11.0  
74997  Unicycle Race Attendant   NaN  
74998       Guidance Counselor  20.0  
74999        Demon of Toxicity   NaN  
75000             Laundry Girl  25.0  

[75001 rows x 6 columns]
```

I want to do a grouping of actors with the first name "Aaron" by year and sort them in ascending order.

So the expected result will look like this:

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: From the data that I have, I want to group them by type, name, and year in ascending order. The result only shows data that have the type "actor" and first name "Aaron".

Comment: Ok -- but what is your question?

Comment: How did you produce the output DataFrame shown in your image? Could you edit into your question the code that you've written so far, as text, not images?

Comment: @PaulH How to do it?

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler Oh sorry, I'm not producing it. It is an example of the end result that I want.

Comment: Did you manually type out the example, or did you produce it with code?

Comment: Manually @PeterLeimbigler

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't really a place to come to ask people to do things for you. There are lots of pandas tutorials explaining how to group and sort data. Read them. When you've got code, but are stuck on particular detail, then come here and ask a question. Right now, my advice would be: put more time into this or hire a consultant

Comment: maybe it helps, if you check this out: [How top ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thank you for the good reminder @PaulH. I already ask a proper question on https://stackoverflow.com/q/71890633/17183759